# Passing variables between two .php pages

Tags: php, parameter-passing

On the catching page i have

```
$storeID= $_REQUEST['store'];
$custID= $_REQUEST['cust'];
```

I have links on different pages to the above page like the following

on page 1.

```
echo "<a class='btn btn-info' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' href='/go-to-store.php?store=" . $KID . "&cust=" . $user_ID . "'>" . "shop" . "</a>";
```

on page 2.

```
echo "<form action='/go-to-store.php' target='_blank' method='post'>" 
. "<input type='hidden' name='store' value='$postid'>" 
. "<input type='hidden' name='cust' value='$user_ID'>" 
. "<button class='btn btn-mini btn-info' type='submit' style='margin-top:5px;'>" 
. "shop" . "</button>";
```

Are both of these ways valid acceptable way of doing things. I have no reason not to show the values to user and there is no harm or motive for anyone to alter these values.

I'm tracing a problem on my site and basically narrowing down any possible scenarios where there could be even a remote chance of something causing the problems i have.

Comment: use `$_SESSION` variables

Comment: use session or cookie to store variables, do dont store passords plain in cookies.

Comment: My site is build on top of wordpress, but the file that is cathcing the info is outside. If i move the cathing file inside wordpress i could easily get the custID without the need to send it...I'm going to change it thatway. Sorry if my questions are not spesific enough.

Answer (score 0):

The `$storeID` looks like it contains data that is relevant only to a specific set of pages on the site, but which people might want to link to. It should form part of the URL so that people can link to it.

The `$custID` looks like it contains data specific to the user, but which should persist across the entire site (and isn't going to change unless the user logs out). It should be stored in a cookie (or stored on the server in a session which is associated with a browser with a cookie) and not passed in each request.

Answer (score 0):

use cookies or session to store data and use them any page you want.

```
<?php
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['storeID'] = $_REQUEST['store'];
     $_SESSION['custID'] = $_REQUEST['cust'];

     // now access session variables from other pages
    echo "Store ID : ". $_SESSION['storeID']."<br />";
    echo "Cust ID". $_SESSION['custID'] 

     // to delete variable
     unset($_SESSION['storeID']);
     unset($_SESSION['custID'])
?>
```

with cookies

```
<?php

    // store varible in cookie for one day 
    setcookie("soreID", $_REQUEST['store'], 60*60*24);
    setcookie("custID", $_REQUEST['cust'], 60*60*24);

    // retrive data
    echo "Store ID : ". $_COOKIE['storeID']."<br />";
    echo "Cust ID". $_COOKIE['custID']   

    // delete cookie 
    setcookie("soreID", $_COOKIE['store'], time()-3600);
    setcookie("custID", $_COOKIE['cust'], time()-3600);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Encode variables by `base64` so your users can't see them without decoding. Put variables into url.

```
$storeID= urlencode(base64_encode($_REQUEST['store']));
$custID= urlencode(base64_encode($_REQUEST['cust']));

// then use following to get data from url:

$storeID= base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['sid']));
$custID= base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['cid']));
```

Option 2: Use sessions. Sessions allow you to save data to server, so they won't show to users.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['storeID'] = $_REQUEST['store'];
$_SESSION['custID'] = $_REQUEST['cust'];

// then use following to get data from sessions:

session_start();
$storeID= $_SESSION['storeID'];
$custID= $_SESSION['custID'];
```

Option 3: Use text files. Keep in mind; i do not recommend this option because it loads server a bit and it doesn't beat other options. (you can use dbs also)

- [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents)
- [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

Edit:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['store']) && isset($_POST['cust'])){
   $_SESSION['storeID'] = $_POST['store'];
   $_SESSION['custID'] = $_POST['cust'];
}
else {
   echo 'please fill are fields.'
}
```

Comment: Both of those are surely more cleaner options compared to what i have now. But is there actually something fundamentally wrong on either of the 2 ways i move the variables? I have tested, tested and tested and always catch the correct values on my receiving page. Yet somehow every now and then one of those values registers as empty? Any reason this might be?

Comment: Problem might not be at my end at all, but I'm just trying to make sure that it's not.

Comment: I bet you haven't checked if user haven't set those fields. Also you should specify which request yu are using, get or post. See my edited code and try it.

Comment: The values are not to be set by users, they are always set up. The value storeid gets its value from my mysql database and is needed to know which store to send customer. And user ids are handled by wordpress, being 0 for all users not logged in and positive unique int for those logged in, userid is used to track who goes to that store. I will test the post instead of request but just dont understand how using request could mess things up.thx for the tips anyway...